# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

After adding Paginate function I'm getting this error

```
$sub_categories = SubCategory::where('id', $id)->first();
$products = Products::where('subcategory_id', $sub_categories->id)->get()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all categories and sub_categories, by any chance?

Comment: I am trying to get all the products using subcategories. I have updated the code.

Comment: what are you trying to archive?  you want to paginate `$products`? or `$sub_categories`

Comment: I am trying to get all products using subcategory @AndySong

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sub_categories = SubCategory::where('id', $id)->first()`, this will only give you `null` or one record, not a collection, so you can not use `->paginate(10);` chain it. You will only get one record at the most, why you need to paginate?

**Update**
so first for the `sub_categories` you do not need to paginate, as you just want one record. so the code should be like this.

```php
$sub_categories = SubCategory::where('id', $id)->first();
```

second, if you want to paginate `$products` you should do this,

```php
if ($sub_categories)
{
    $products = Products::where('subcategory_id', $sub_categories->id)->paginate(10);
}
```